# Django Rejecting POST with Firefox RESTClient & Jersey, Works with Chrome POSTMAN and curl

Tags: django, rest, jersey, rest-client

I don't know much about Django but I need to write a client that interacts with a Django REST service.

GET works for me in all 4 interfaces I've tried: Chrome POSTMAN, Firefox RESTClient, Jersey Client in Java, and curl.

POST gets rejected by Django with a 400 BAD REQUEST in Jersey and RESTClient, but not in the other two.  Unfortunately the ultimate solution is to use Jersey so that's a big problem.

I'm guessing at this point that it's the client encoding that Django doesn't like so I'm hoping someone out there can tell me the difference between POSTMAN and RESTClient?  (I'm sending the data as "raw" json in POSTMAN)

Here's my jersey code:

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource resource = client.resource("rest service endpoint");
resource.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
resource.post("{"\name\":\"test\",\"age\":29}");  // Returns a 400 Bad request
```

Posting {"name":"test","age":29} to Chrome works.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have faced issues where Nginx (Apache too) doesn't allow headers with underscore to pass through. So basically HEADER_NAME doesn't pass through. Have to make it HEADER-NAME. I usually use POSTMAN and FF RESTClient.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out from Jersey at least.  Doing a tcpdump revealed that my application/json header wasn't making it through so I got that sorted out by doing ...

```
WebResource.Builder resource = client.resource("web server").type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

Then it worked.  Still no idea why this doesn't work in REST Client so if someone knows that let me know!